# R: como evitar que las etiquetas de un gráfico se solapen

Tags: r

Estoy creando un bitplot (un gráfico cualquiera) a partir de un data frame. El problema es que al crearlo me solapa las etiquetas:

[image: r la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como evitar esto y que alternativas puedo usar. Este es el script que he usado para realizar el bitplot:

A partir de una matriz he ejecutado el siguiente código:

```
SNP_3.a.region_SS.prca <- prcomp(m_SNP_3.a.region_SS_m, center = TRUE)

Biplot_SNP_3.a.region_SS<-biplot(SNP_3.a.region_SS.prca,choices=1:2,scale=1,main="CMV3_3.a.region_SS",pc.biplot=FALSE)
```

También me gustaría saber si existe alguna alternativa que no sea por medio de adobe ilustrator para delimitar mediante círculos aquellos puntos que están más cercanos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con `biplot()` tienes algunas opciones que sin duda mejorarán la lectura del gráfico, aunque por la naturaleza del mismo es muy difícil lograr que no existan solapamientos. Veamos este ejemplo:

```
require(graphics)
ua <- prcomp(USArrests, center = TRUE)
biplot(ua)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunas mejoras que podemos plantear:

- Con `col` podemos establecer los colores de las dos clases de etiquetas, podemos destacar las etiquetas de las flechas, haciendo las otras de un gris más claro
- También con `cex` podremos modificar los tamaños de letra
- Y por último, podemos usar `expand`, que establece el factor de expansión de las flecha, con lo cual podremos separar de alguna forma las etiquetas, pero será necesario ajustar los límites con `xlim` y `ylim`

Ejemplo:

```
biplot(ua, 
       expand=3, 
       col=c('#a9a9aa', '#d1141e'),
       cex=c(0.6, 1),
       xlim=c(-1, 0.4),
       ylim=c(-0.3, 0.3))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No creo que con biplot se pueda mejorar mucho más, tal vez debas buscar alguna solución alternativa, hay varios paquetes, creo que el te recomendaría es `factoextra`:

```
library("factoextra") 
ua <- prcomp(USArrests, center = TRUE)
fviz_pca_biplot(ua, 
                repel=TRUE, 
                col.ind="#a9a9aa")
```

Particularmente para lo que buscas, es muy útil el parámetro `repel`, al habilitarlo hace que las etiquetas se separen de cada punto y se les grafique una linea para conectar ambos elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Algunas soluciones al problema del overploting o superposición de elementos en un gráfico.

## Aumentar el tamaño del gráfico.

El overploting es un problema relativo. En este caso eso quiere decir que depende del tamaño del gráfico que estás haciendo. Aún el gráfico más "limpio" tiene problemas de superposición si el tamaño en el que lo generamos es muy pequeño o si los márgenes, leyendas, títulos, etc. limitan el área del gráfico propiamente dicho. Entonces hay dos alternativas:

- Aumentar el tamaño absoluto del gráfico. La forma de hacerlo dependerá de dónde se está generando el gráfico. Si es para visualizarlo en el área de gráficos de Rstudio se puede dar zoom y verlo en pantalla completa. Si es para impresión en un documento  usando `rmarkdown` se pude especificar el tamaño en pulgadas en la línea de configuración de bloque de código que produce el gráfico con `fig.height=` y `fig.width=` para la altura y el ancho respectivamente.
- "Limpiar" el gráfico de elementos innecesarios o achicar los márgenes. Lo primero es más fácil con `ggplot`, lo segundo con los gráficos base de R.

## Graficar con una función que reubique las etiquetas

Si no es posible aumentar el tamaño del gráfico se puede usar, para tu caso en particular, la función `fviz_pca` de la librería `factoextra`. Esa función hace el tipo de gráfico que buscas a partir de un objeto resultante de `prcomp` y tiene el argumento `repel= TRUE` con el que usa `ggrepel` para evitar la superposición de etiquetas. Los resultados no siempre son los mejores y a veces el gráfico se ve feo o se dificulta la lectura, pero vale la pena probarlo.

## Ejemplo:

Como no se incluyen datos en la pregunta voy a usar `USAarrests`, que vienen en el ejemplo de `prcomp` al que podemos invocar con `example(prcomp)`.

```
# Genero el objeto prcomp
resPCA <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = T)

# Lo grafico con la función base prcomp

biplot(resPCA)

# Lo grafico con fviz_pca()

library(factoextra)
fviz_pca(resPCA, repel = T)
```

### Resultado con `biplot`

> Retocando los márgenes con `par()` podría mejorar, pero es tedioso hacerlo manualmente. El manejo de márgenes es una de las mejores características de `ggplot` y derivadas, como las de `factoextra`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Resulado con `fviz_pca`

> Produce un objeto de la clase `ggplot`, por lo que podrías modificarlo añadiendo elemento con el operador `+`, como cualquier otro gráfico de `ggplot`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bastante mejor el segundo gráfico, por la función `repel` que reubica las etiquetas y también porque al estar basado en `ggplot()` tiene buen manejo automático de márgenes.

Con `help(fviz_pca))` vas a encontrar algunas opciones para personalizar el gráfico. En [este enlace](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factoextra-r-package-easy-multivariate-data-analyses-and-elegant-visualization#main-functions-in-the-factoextra-package) hay guías (en inglés, lamentablemente) para usar toda la librería, que está excelentemente documentada. Verás que la opción `addEllipses = TRUE` podría servir para resolver tu segunda pregunta.

> Feliz 2019, algo atrasado.